# Automatically implement virtual functions depending on sister classes

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Is there an idiom I can use to help with implementing virtual functions that depend on the presence of a base class? For example, I have

```
class B {/* some abstract interface. */};

class A
{
public:
  virtual B* getB() {return nullptr;}
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
  B* getB() override {return this;}

  /* Implement B's interface here.*/
};
```

and I usually want to implement `getB` like this - could I somehow avoid having to repeat this for all leaf classes? I potentially have a few interface classes like B,

I know that one way to do it is to virtually inherit from A in both C and B, but I'd like to keep B unrelated from A, if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it all in A:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual B* getB() {return dynamic_cast<B*>(this);}
};
```

Note: `virtual` here is just to make class A polymorphic, a requirement of this use of `dynamic_cast`.  We don't intend to override `getB()`.

Comment: In what way is this "a requirement of this use of `dynamic_cast`? Or is it about overriding the function in the child classes?

Comment: C++11 5.2.7 Dynamic cast says 'Otherwise, v shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type'.  This is one of the 'otherwise' cases.  The source type needs to be polymorphic for down- and cross- casts.

Comment: `getB()` itself doesn't need to be virtual if A has other virtual functions.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't this case covered by 5.2.7/5 (instead of /6 which you quoted)?

Comment: No.  That paragraph covers upcasts.